# Удаление лишних функций js

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, webpack

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема. Есть огромный js фреймворк с кучей функций, есть ли возможность с помощью например gulp вырезать только функции которые используются на странице? Для css есть прекрасный инструмент uncss, есть ли что-то подобное на JS, буду очень благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: Вообще гелп удаляет не используемые функции т.к. в там используется UglifyJS. Вы можете использовать его отдельно в принципе. PS: Хотя скорее всего там не функции а методы и классы.

Comment: Хорошо, а есть ли возможность удалять методы и классы лишние, возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: Полностью автоматически - нет.